# How do I assign a static class property that needs quotations in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

I use a library [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) which wraps Node's require method to allow Mock object injection. One of the features is that it extends the mock object with the original so missing properties are filled in. You can turn this off by setting a property on the mock object called `@noCallThru` like so:

```
MockObj =
  stubFunc: ->
  "@noCallThru": true

proxyquire "path/to/module",
  "path/to/mocked_module": MockObj
```

Some modules are constructor functions (classes) so to mock them you use CoffeeScript's class system. However the use of `@noCallThru` is checked on the returned object (in this case the class) and since it is not an instance will not be using prototype. The `@noCallThru` needs to be a static property of the class.

How can I define a static property to a CoffeeScript class which needs quotations? The best I could figure out was to inject strait JavaScript like so:

```
class MockClass
  stubFunc: ->
  `MockClass['@noCallThru'] = true`
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to inject it as JavaScript.  You can do this:

```
class MockClass
  stubFunc: ->
  @['@noCallThru'] = true
```

(since in the class definition, `this` or `@` refers to the class/constructor itself)

The above code compiles to:

```
var MockClass;

MockClass = (function() {
  MockClass.name = 'MockClass';
  function MockClass() {}
  MockClass.prototype.stubFunc = function() {};
  MockClass['@noCallThru'] = true;
  return MockClass;
})();
```

Comment: `@['@noCallThru'] = true` would be closer to the usual `@class_prop = x`.

Comment: @muistooshort: Thanks, moved it into the first part of the answer.